# Web Audio Delay Node guidance

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

trying to wire up a delay effect for a little Web Audio app and can't seem to get it to sound good.  Seems simple enough but not getting the results I'd like.  Would like to have the delay note repeat over and over and slowly die away.  I can implement the gain part of that but can't seem to get the feedback loop part so the delay continues.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here's the relevant code.  Added a second delay in hopes of extending but not quite what I was looking for.

```
            var osc = ctx.createOscillator();
            var gainNode = ctx.createGain();

            if (addDelay === false) {
                osc.connect(gainNode);
                gainNode.connect(ctx.destination);
            }

            else if (addDelay === true) {
                var delay = ctx.createDelay();
                var delay2 = ctx.createDelay();
                delay.delayTime.value = 0.35;
                delay2.delayTime.value = 0.5;
                osc.connect(gainNode);
                gainNode.connect(ctx.destination);
                gainNode.connect(delay);
                gainNode.connect(delay2);
                delay.connect(gainNode);
                delay2.connect(gainNode);
                delay.connect(ctx.destination);
                delay2.connect(ctx.destination);        
            }
            gainNode.gain.value = 0.0;
            gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(0.75, ctx.currentTime, 0.1);
            gainNode.gain.setTargetAtTime(0.0, ctx.currentTime + sustainFnl, 0.01);
            osc.frequency.value = hz * octave / 4;
            osc.type = waveType;
            osc.start();
            osc.stop(ctx.currentTime + sustainFnl + 0.01);
        }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer in this article by Chris Lowis: http://blog.chrislowis.co.uk/2014/07/23/dub-delay-web-audio-api.html

```
var ctx = new AudioContext();
var audioElement = $('#feedback audio')[0];

audioElement.addEventListener('play', function(){
var source = ctx.createMediaElementSource(audioElement);

var delay = ctx.createDelay();
delay.delayTime.value = 0.5;

var feedback = ctx.createGain();
feedback.gain.value = 0.8;

delay.connect(feedback);
feedback.connect(delay);

source.connect(delay);
source.connect(ctx.destination);
delay.connect(ctx.destination);
```

Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I did not try this out, but in the `addDelay === true` case, maybe you want to delete this line:

`gainNode.connect(ctx.destination);`

I'm also not sure why you have 

`gainNode.connect(delay);
gainNode.connect(delay2);`

Did you mean to cascade the two delay nodes together?  And if you did, you could just use one delay node with a longer delay time.

Here is a small example that seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/n6782bpf/ Not sure if this is what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks Raymond, Yes I was trying out adding two delays to see if that would increase the results.  I will play around with that this evening and update you on the results.  Thanks again.

Comment: Was able to try that out.  I guess I didn't clarify enough in my original post but what I'm looking for is a delay that will continue ringing several times and not just once.  In other words, say I play a note with a sixteenth duration.  Would love to hear that note played several times, every .25s or so, until it eventually dies away.  Hope that makes sense!   What would I need to do to achieve that sort of delay?  thanks!